# Failed to recognize value `undefined` for property `Regional_Indicator`. CKEditor 5 issue with react hook form

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor

I am trying to use CKEditor 5 with react hook form but its giving errors:

```
/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/ckeditor.js: Failed to recognize value `undefined` for property `Regional_Indicator`.
```

My code:

```
<CKEditor
        className={`form-control w-full border-red-500 ${
          errors["body"] ? "border-red-500" : ""
        }`}
        Co
        borderColor="red"
        editor={ClassicEditor}
        data={item.body}
        onReady={(editor) => {
          const editorData = editor.getData();
          setValue("body", editorData, {
            shouldDirty: true
          });
        }}
        onChange={(event, editor) => {
          const editorData = editor.getData();
          setValue("body", editorData, {
            shouldDirty: true
          });
        }}
      />
```

Here, is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ckeditor-ujpt85?file=/src/App.js:993-1579) link